# element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium

Newbie to selenium! I'm trying to list a house for sale on Craigslist using selenium.

And I am having trouble selecting an option from a drop-down select box.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/apps/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://post.craigslist.org/k/tKNKfCkr6hG7ghq71YXqTA/oj7w8?s=edit')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.housing_type > option[value='6']").click()
```

I get the following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable:
>   Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Using "Select" also gives the same error:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

housing_type = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.housing_type"))
housing_type.select_by_visible_text('house')
```

The element is present:

```
housing_type = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.housing_type")
housing_type
```

But it is not intractable:

```
housing_type.click()
```

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I noticed the select element is hidden and selection is controlled by next element overplayed on the select box.

```html
<label class="json-form-item select housing_type std variant-select">
    <div class="label-wrapper"><span class="label">housing type</span></div>
    <select tabindex="1" name="housing_type" class="json-form-input no-js housing_type" id="ui-id-1" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1" selected="">apartment</option>
    <option value="2">condo</option>
    <option value="3">cottage/cabin</option>
    <option value="4">duplex</option>
    <option value="5">flat</option>
    <option value="6">house</option>
    <option value="7">in-law</option>
    <option value="8">loft</option>
    <option value="9">townhouse</option>
    <option value="10">manufactured</option>
    <option value="11">assisted living</option>
    <option value="12">land</option>
    </select>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" id="ui-id-1-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="ui-id-1-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 88%;">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">apartment</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

I am able to make the selection by activating the element and using down/return keys as follows, but this is not an elegant solution.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

housing_type = driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-1-button")
housing_type.click()
for i in range(0,5):
    housing_type.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
housing_type.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Is there a better way to make the selection?

Comment: Is the element inside an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Yes, there is an iframe, you have to switch on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an item from the Housing type dropdown on the page you provided, I would first invoke `WebDriverWait` on the dropdown menu to ensure that it exists before you try to interact with it. Then, you can use Javascript to click the dropdown trigger and expand the options.

After that, we invoke `WebDriverWait` once more on the option we wish to click. The following code sample will click the option 'flat':

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# start driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/apps/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://post.craigslist.org/k/tKNKfCkr6hG7ghq71YXqTA/oj7w8?s=edit')

# wait for dropdown to exist
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(@class, 'housing_type')]")))

# expand housing type dropdown using javascript
dropdown_trigger = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(@class, 'housing_type')]/span/span[contains(@class, 'ui-icon')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dropdown_trigger)

# select an option -- this selects 'flat'
dropdown_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='flat']")))
dropdown_option.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a problem with how the overlay/dropdown is being used.

> I noticed the select element is hidden and selection is controlled by next element overplayed on the select box.

Since the visibility of the dropdown is controlled by some overlay, you'll be forced to click on the dropdown button in order to activate the overlay and make the dropdown button visible. After the dropdown button becomes visible, you should be able to use the Selenium code without further issue. Namely, this snippet of code should be good to use:

```
housing_type = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.housing_type"))
housing_type.select_by_visible_text('house')
```

I suggest using this approach, rather than your alternative of using the `Keys.DOWN` actions, as this is a better use of Selenium's built-in functions

Comment: @natn2323...thank you for the feedback. That didn't work in this particular case. I was getting the same error.