# Dropdown Element with option text values in ul list - Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

[image]

I want to select the option with the value "DATE" using Selenium. The thing about it is that the option text is set in another part which is the ul list.
I tried some of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534665/element-not-interactable-element-is-not-currently-visible-and-may-not-be-manipu) that I found but none of them worked.
Here's my code:

```
        WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@data-test="FilterSorts"]')))
        dropdown_trigger = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@data-test="FilterSorts"]')
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dropdown_trigger)
        dropdown_option = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='DATE']")))
        dropdown_option.click()
```

I also tried this and still got the same error:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@data-test="FilterSorts"]')))
dropdown_trigger = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@data-test="FilterSorts"]')
select = Select(dropdown_trigger)
select.select_by_value('DATE').click()
```

error:

> dropdown_trigger =
> browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@data-test="FilterSorts"]')
> Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible
> and may not be manipulated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
#Identify the element
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Most Recent')]") 
#Apply Javascript of click action
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```